# Detailed Setup for App Registration Endpoint Version 2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I followed the steps in the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

How to setup for the steps below? Please provide detailed steps.

> If you use v2 endpoints, use the scope you created for the backend-app
> in the Default scope field. Also, make sure to set the value for the
> accessTokenAcceptedVersion property to 2 in your application manifest.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console

Comment: Hello @Pingpong, Please refer this document  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#configure-the-app-manifest

Comment: Thanks. I can change `accessTokenAcceptedVersion ` based on your link. But how can I change for this "use the scope you created for the backend-app in the Default scope field."?

Comment: Do the changes apply to the backend app or client app?

Answer (score 0):

To configure the application manifest: [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#configure-the-app-manifest)

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/). Search for and select the Azure Active Directory service.
2. Select App registrations.
3. Select the app you want to configure.
4. From the app's Overview page, select the Manifest section. A web-based manifest editor opens, allowing you to edit the manifest within the portal.

For V2 endpoint  set accessTokenAcceptedVersion  to 2.
That Specifies the access token,the version expected by the resource.

```
“accessTokenAcceptedVersion”: 2,
```

And yes the changes apply to the backend app . [Refer](https://blog.torib.io/2020/07/15/protect-an-api-by-using-oauth-2-0-with-azure-active-directory-and-api-management/)